# Showing HTML content just after login in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any way to call HTML from JS function? Below is the code ref:
The login method in ASP.Net MVC is implemented like this:

```
<div>
<button id = "btnSubmit" name ="btnSubmit" class="pop-submit" value="submit" type = "submit" onclick="loginl();">sign in </button>
```

```
 <script type="text/javescript">
 function loginl(){

   $("#inprogress").attr("style","display:block";height:50px;width:100%;");
   // HTML call to show message from here
   document.forms["formlogin"].submit();
   return true;
  }

 </script>
```

On click login, that is before submit, I would like to implement a piece of HTML:

> Message: Thank you for contacting us. Please visit our new url( this url will go here). The following are most recent changes:
>
> - Item1
> - Item2

Is there any easiest way to achieve this? I was trying using "Alert" or a "Prompt". However, it seems there is no provision to include HTML/CSHTML in this.

This is how, I'm trying to do:

```
 <script type="text/javescript">
 function loginl(){

   $("#inprogress").attr("style","display:block";height:50px;width:100%;");
   alert('message' + $(this).html("DiLogBox")); //can I not do something like this?
   document.forms["formlogin"].submit();
   return true;
  }

 </script>
```

Then my HTML will be :

```
<div id = "DiLogBox">
......
</div>
```

Here is no validation. Simply show the message.

Comment: Showing content as HTML format using alert???

Comment: Yes. Or Any other ways are OK also. Please note, I can not change the way login is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just use the pop up box to assist you. Thats it

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that what you're really trying to achieve is showing a message inside a modal like window. There is two options here: Vanilla JS or using some third party like [jQuery modal](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiPoJvon_rqAhUDca0KHVkqADgQFjACegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjquerymodal.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw3_0HpXRjV0JsKCeY3PYsmQ). Here is another [article](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) on how to implement it using Vanilla JS.

You can then add an event listener to the form and prevent to send it until the user closes the modal.

Here is a simple example:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

var showModal = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

var hideModal = function(){
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

//Prevent the form to submit
document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  var form = this;
  e.preventDefault();
  showModal();
  span.addEventListener("click", function(){
    hideModal();
    form.submit();
    alert("form submitted");
  });
});
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="my-name">Name</label>
  <input id="my-name" type="text" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have HTML and able to show on the same login popup window. However, the requirement is to display the HTML content [ that I already have] "on click login/sign in" I believe this can be achieved in CSHTML  and no need to implement anything in the controller/ .cs code.

Comment: can't you modify your loginl function in anyway then? Let's say to prevent the default submit there and register the modal?

Comment: I think I got it wrong since the beginning. So you're trying to show the html content after the login was successful?

Comment: The message should come just after user clicked on login "OR"  Yes, showing a message once login successful should work as well.

Comment: I can't really see why using a custom modal is not a solution, am I missing something here? You don't have permission to modify the current HTML markup or something?